# Como comparar una variable varias veces con un >=

Tags: php

Lo que dice el título, estoy haciendo un proyecto y en una parte específica quiero sumarle 1 al valor de una variable, espero que con el código entiendan mi duda

```
$resultado = $_POST['resultado'];
```

Supongamos que el valor enviado por el formulario es 10.
Y tengo una escala de resultados que van de -18 a 18, es decir.

```
-10 a -18 = N
-1 a -9 = LN
 0 = S
 1 a 9 = LP
 10 a 18 = P
```

Entonces...

```
if ($resultado == 0) {
  $S++;
} elseif ($resultado >= 1) {
  $LP++;
} elseif ($resultado >= 10) {
  $P++;
} elseif ($resultado <= -1) {
  $LN++;
} elseif ($resultado <= -10) {
  $N++;
}
```

Cuando el resultado es del 1 al 9 la variable `$LP` se incrementa, el problema es que cuando el resultado va del 10 al 18 en lugar de incrementarse la variable `$P` se incrementa la variable `$LP` y lo mismo me pasa con las variables `$LN` y `$N`.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que validar el valor de tu resultado verificando que se encuentre entre los rangos que has definido:

```
if ($resultado == 0) {
  $S++;
} elseif ($resultado >= 1 && $resultado <= 9) {
  $LP++;
} elseif ($resultado >= 10 && $resultado <= 18) {
  $P++;
} elseif ($resultado >= -9 && $resultado <= -1) {
  $LN++;
} elseif ($resultado >= -18 && $resultado <= -10) {
  $N++;
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estas teniendo, es que en este caso, el orden de los `if` si altera el resultado.

Fijate como lo tenes ahora:

```
if ($resultado == 0){
    $S++;
}elseif ($resultado >= 1){
    $LP++;
}elseif ($resultado >= 10){
    $P++;
}elseif ($resultado <= -1){
    $LN++;
}elseif ($resultado <= -10){
    $N++;
}
```

Si resultado es 3, entra en el primer `if`. Si el resultado es 15, es mayor que uno, entonces entra en el primer `if`. Si el resultado es -3, entra en el tercero.

Es importante tener en cuenta que si vas a hacer algo así, el orden de revisión de los parámetros es muy importante.

Prueba con algo así:

```
if ($resultado == 0){
    $S++;
}elseif ($resultado <= -10){
    $N++;
}elseif ($resultado <= -1){
    $LN++;
}elseif ($resultado >= 10){
    $P++;
}elseif ($resultado >= 1){
    $LP++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si realmente quieres hacer esta comparación:

```
-10 a -18 = N
-1  a -9  = LN
 0  =       S
 1  a  9  = LP
 10 a 18  = P
```

Una opción interesante podría ser la siguiente:

- Creas una función a la que le pasas: el valor actual, los valores del rango, y el valor de cada variable **por referencia**.
- La función creará un array de valores con el rango mediante `range` y buscará si dentro del array está el valor de `$v`, si lo encuentra, aumentará el valor de cada caso pasando por referencia.

El código sería más o menos así:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/NXVA43359)**</kbd>

```
/*Probar una serie de valores*/

$arrPruebas=array(-11,-2,0,7,12);
foreach($arrPruebas as $v){

    /*Inicializar variables para fines de prueba*/
    $S=0;$LP=0;$P=0;$LN=0;$N=0;  

    /*Comparaciones*/
    inRange($v,-10,-18,$N);
    inRange($v,-1,-9,$LN);
    inRange($v,0,0,$S);
    inRange($v,1,9,$LP);
    inRange($v,10,18,$P);

    /*Salida*/
    echo "Prueba siendo $"."v=$v".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    echo "\tS\tLP\tP\tLN\tN".PHP_EOL;
    echo "\t$S\t$LP\t$P\t$LN\t$N".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."***".PHP_EOL;   

}

/*Función para comparar si está en el rango*/

function inRange($v, $min, $max, &$ref){
    $val=range($min,$max);
    if ( in_array ($v, $val) ) 
        {
            $ref++;
        }
}
```

**Resultados de pruebas por caso:**

```
- Prueba siendo $v=-11

    S   LP  P   LN  N
    0   0   0   0   1
```

---

```
 - Prueba siendo $v=-2

    S   LP  P   LN  N
    0   0   0   1   0
```

---

```
 - Prueba siendo $v=0

    S   LP  P   LN  N
    1   0   0   0   0
```

---

```
 - Prueba siendo $v=7

    S   LP  P   LN  N
    0   1   0   0   0
```

---

```
 - Prueba siendo $v=12

    S   LP  P   LN  N
    0   0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa mas

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$S=0;$LP=0;$P=0;$LN=0;$N=0;
echo "$S;$LP;$P;$LN;$N;".PHP_EOL;

$resultado = 1;

function between($n, $a, $b) {
    return ($n-$a)*($n-$b) <= 0;
}

if ($resultado==0) :
  $S++;
elseif (between($resultado, 1, 9)) :
  $LP++;
elseif (between($resultado, 10, 18)) :
  $P++;
elseif (between($resultado, -9, -1)) :
  $LN++;
elseif (between($resultado, -18, -10)) :
  $N++;
endif;

echo "$S;$LP;$P;$LN;$N;".PHP_EOL;
```

implementación de `betweeen` basada en https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049555/1423096